# Cannot send email to gmail account from postfix

Tags: gmail, plesk, postfix-mta, milter

I am having problem in sending emails in gmail account. I see them in the queue but they are not proccessing. 
Looking at the logs I noticed that when I try to send to gmail i receive the following:

```
Dec 5 12:55:36 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/smtpd[8797]: connect from adsl-215.176.58.243.tellas.gr[176.58.243.215]
Dec 5 12:55:36 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/smtpd[8797]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:12768: Connection refused
Dec 5 12:55:37 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/smtpd[8797]: 51E6A4413: client=adsl-215.176.58.243.tellas.gr[176.58.243.215], sasl_method=DIGEST-MD5, sasl_username=donotreply@edentalbook.com
Dec 5 12:55:37 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/cleanup[8801]: 51E6A4413: message-id=<002a01d24edd$baa3c680$2feb5380$@com>
Dec 5 12:55:37 lvps81-41-130-77 opendkim[31319]: 51E6A4413: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=edentalbook.com)
Dec 5 12:55:37 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/qmgr[29641]: 51E6A4413: from=<donotreply@edentalbook.com>, size=2808, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 5 12:55:37 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/qmgr[29641]: warning: connect to transport private/smtp-ipv4: No such file or directory
Dec 5 12:55:37 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/error[8802]: 51E6A4413: to=<grnelgeo@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.62, delays=0.61/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Dec 5 12:55:40 lvps81-41-130-77 postfix/smtpd[8797]: disconnect from adsl-215.176.58.243.tellas.gr[176.58.243.215]
```

Comment: Check for chroot and try to disable it http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#no_chroot